# What is the meaning of "sweat" in this context?

Tags: meaning, headlinese

The headline is:
"Let’s All Sweat Student Debt"

I can't figure it out what Sweat means. seems like it is a verb in the phrase/sentence what is the meaning of "Sweat" is this phrase/sentence???

Comment: It helps to link the article or at least explain what the article is about.

Answer (score 3):

More context would be helpful, but it's most likely definition 9 under "transitive verb" in [this Merriam-Webster entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweat):

> slang : to worry about
> *doesn't sweat the small stuff*

... meaning "Let's all worry about student debt," even if other sources have told us "don't sweat it."